# How to convert URLs imported from .csv to string - Python

Tags: python, string, csv, arguments

I'm attempting to read URLs from a .csv file to begin a loop.  My csv file only contains URLs.
While trying to read the URL from the csv file, i'm receiving this error: `Message: invalid argument: 'url' must be a string`

I've only included relevant code.  Thank you in advance for any insight/help.

```
from csv import reader, writer
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

with open('work2.csv', 'r') as f:


   urls = thereader = reader(f)

 
   for url in urls:
      driver.get(url)
```

[CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYmtO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read from a csv file it will read each row in form of list so to get the url you just take the first one.

```
from csv import reader, writer
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

with open('work2.csv', 'r') as f:


   urls = thereader = reader(f)

 
   for url in urls:
      driver.get(url[0])
```

Comment: thank you! I'm very new to this, now I'm just receiving an invalid argument error.

Comment: can you add an image of your csv file in your question. CSV file will give an idea what data is being readed

Comment: yes of course, added to the original post

Comment: I found out the mistake use this driver.get(url[0]).

Comment: Thank you SO much, that was the last piece I needed to finish my script, thank you for taking the time!!!

Comment: No problem bro always avaliable for the community.